# Cannot go to a specific route

Tags: angular, firebase, angular-cli

I have made a simple routing in my app and everything works fine on localhost, but when i upload dist folder on hosting, after `ng build` i cannot go to specific links, when i type them on my browser, such as `www.mydomain.com/login`. I import `routableComponents` in my app.module declatrations.

### app-routing.module.ts

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    pathMatch: 'full',
    redirectTo: 'main/posts'
  },
  {
    path: 'main',
    component: MainComponent,
    children: [
      {
        path: 'posts',
        component: PostListComponent,

      },
      {
        path:'posts/watching',
        component: WatchingComponent
      },
      {
        path: 'posts/reading',
        component: ReadingComponent
      },
      {
        path: 'posts/brickets',
        component: BricketsComponent
      },

  },
  {
    path: 'login',
    component: LoginComponent
  }

];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})

export class AppRoutingModule {
}

export const routableComponents = [
  PostListComponent,
  LoginComponent,
  WatchingComponent,
  ReadingComponent,
  BricketsComponent,
  MainComponent
];
```

Comment: deployed it's not working, show how did you deploy

Comment: Are you getting a 404 response? If so it's most likely your web server not understanding the request URL and not an Angular issue. You'll need to implement some sort of URL Rewrite (depending on what web server you're using).

Comment: I deployed project once on firebase hosting but it's display same error, and once on the diffrent hosting by FTP. The error displayed is 404. I also noticed that when i come back to URL (by Alt + left Arrow) it cannot GET CSS files.

Comment: @Dr.Glob Have you set up your firebase rewrites in `firebase.json` to redirect to your index page and set `<base href="/">`?